# Ubuntu One Oauth login from PHP

Tags: ubuntu-one, php, cloud

I have searched the whole internet trying to find a simple example that could point me in the right direction, but no luck, so here comes my questions:

I want to log into Ubuntu One and sync (or almost read) files from my web page, all done with PHP. The needs to reach files are all described in that page: https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/account_admin/issue_tokens/cloud/

I am able to complete the first request with:

```
$url = 'https://login.ubuntu.com/api/1.0/authentications?ws.op=authenticate&token_name=Ubuntu%20One%20@%20try1';
$data = curlPetition(array('URL'=>$url,'USERPWD'=>'user:pass'));
$ar = fopen('uOne','w');fwrite($ar,$data['responseBody']);fclose($ar);
$tokenA = json_decode($data['responseBody'],1);
```

Ok, curlPetition only makes basic curl petitions. Note that you need a valid user:pass ubuntu one account. I get the response correctly in json with "consumer_secret" , "token" , "consumer_key" , "name" , "token_secret". Even the entry appear listed in the ubuntu one's granted apps.

I hace installed the most new OAuth PCL php extensión and its working good. but when I try to:

```
    $api_url = 'https://one.ubuntu.com/api/file_storage/v1/';
    $conskey = $tokenA['consumer_key'];
    $conssec = $tokenA['consumer_secret'];
    $token = $tokenA['token'];
    $secret = $tokenA['token_secret'];
    $oauth = new OAuth($conskey,$conssec,OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1,OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI);
    $oauth->enableDebug();
    $oauth->enableSSLChecks();
    $oauth->setToken($token,$secret);
    $oauth->fetch($api_url.'~/Ubuntu%20One/');
    print_r($oauth->getLastResponse());
```

I get moved to the "OpenID transaction in progress" page where you pass when doing a manual web login. Im definitely doing something wrong. I tried to get the second step from https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/account_admin/issue_tokens/cloud/ with $oauth->fetch, $oauth->getAccessToken and $oauth->getRequestToken, same response on all with 403 error :S

I was trying to figure how the payload works but the main examples are writed with python, using "import ubuntuone.couch.auth as auth" that makes the token stuff almost automatic.

I'll love to get some hints. Thanks

Comment: I was trying all examples with PHP, after getting the tokens (step1), than signed with the token itself (step2), which are OK, on step3 when I should get the file list, server returns: Forbidden (403), CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. Searching on Internet, I found this as a bug report [(https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers/+bug/686697)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers/+bug/686697), but it's marked as "fixed", however for me it still not working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the problem was that step 2 of the "create a new token" workflow, defined on https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/account_admin/issue_tokens/cloud/, was failing with a 503 for you because the service was down at a couple of points this weekend. You'll need to trap this situation and deal with it (a 503 indicates that you should retry the request later, as per standard HTTP).

I've tested the below PHP (beware: I am not a PHP hacker, so it might not be the most idiomatic code) and it works fine for me. It goes through three steps:

1. Create a new token in Ubuntu SSO (login.ubuntu.com) ([API docs](https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/account_admin/issue_tokens/cloud/))
2. Tell Ubuntu One about that new token ([API docs](https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/account_admin/issue_tokens/cloud/))
3. Use that new token to sign a request to the Ubuntu One files API ([API docs](https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/files/store_files/cloud/))

You'll see the individual parts commented below. Remember that this requests and gets a brand new token; once you have the token (after step 2), save it somewhere; don't request a new one every time.

```
<?php
function curlPetition($arr){
    $curl = curl_init($arr['URL']);
    if($arr['USERPWD']){curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $arr['USERPWD']);}  
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,2);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $out = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $data['responseBody'] = $out;
    return $data;
}

/* Define username and password details */
$email_address = 'stuart.langridge@canonical.com';
$password = 'MY PASSWORD';

/* Step 1: Get a new OAuth token from Ubuntu Single-Sign-On */
$url = 'https://login.ubuntu.com/api/1.0/authentications?ws.op=authenticate&token_name=Ubuntu%20One%20@%20try1';
$data = curlPetition(array('URL'=>$url,'USERPWD'=> $email_address.':'.$password));
$tokenA = json_decode($data['responseBody'],1);

/* Set up that new token for use in OAuth requests */
$conskey = $tokenA['consumer_key'];
$conssec = $tokenA['consumer_secret'];
$token = $tokenA['token'];
$secret = $tokenA['token_secret'];
$oauth = new OAuth($conskey,$conssec,OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1,OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI);
$oauth->enableDebug();
$oauth->enableSSLChecks();
$oauth->setToken($token,$secret);

/* Step 2: tell Ubuntu One about the new token (signed with the token itself) */
$tell_u1_about_token_url = 'https://one.ubuntu.com/oauth/sso-finished-so-get-tokens/' . $email_address;
$oauth->fetch($tell_u1_about_token_url);
print_r($oauth->getLastResponse());

/* Step 3: use the token to make a request to the Files API */
$api_url = 'https://one.ubuntu.com/api/file_storage/v1/';
$oauth->fetch($api_url.'~/Ubuntu%20One/');
print_r($oauth->getLastResponse());
?>
```

Comment: Incidentally, if you decide to write a PHP wrapper library for the Ubuntu One Files API, tell me about it and I'll link to it from the documentation. I'd also love to see your website when done!

Comment: i'm interested in this, too. When you say "once you have the token (after step 2), save it somewhere" the token is related to the application that use the api or to the user? I think to the user but it is always the same or it delete itsef after logout or when the session finish?

Comment: The token is sort of related to both. The token is user-specific, but it's also a separate token which has been issued to your application for use with that user. It remains valid forever, but the user can go and delete that token (and therefore revoke your application's access to Ubuntu One as them). The token is not for an app -- it's not an API key. Your app should not hardcode a token into its source!

Answer (score 2):

Code from one first-step-class to talk with ubuntuOne

```
<?php
class ubuntuOne{
    var $curl = array('cookieSrc'=>'cookie.txt','enableCookies'=>false);
    var $auth = array('consumer_key'=>false,'consumer_secret'=>false,'token'=>false,'token_secret'=>false);
    var $oauth = false;
    function ubuntuOne(){

    }
    function u1_getRoot(){
        if($this->oauth === false){return false;}
        $url = 'https://one.ubuntu.com/api/file_storage/v1';
        $this->oauth->fetch($url);
        print_r($this->oauth->getLastResponse());
    }
    function u1_listFolder($path){
        if($this->oauth === false){return false;}
        //FIXME: parse $path
        $url = 'https://one.ubuntu.com/api/file_storage/v1';
        //FIXME: $path debe terminar en '/'
        $url .= str_replace(' ','%20',$path);

        $this->oauth->fetch($url);
        $lr = $this->oauth->getLastResponse();
        if($lr === '{"error": "not found"}'){return false;}
        print_r($this->oauth->getLastResponse());
    }
    function u1_createFolder($name,$path = ''){
        //FIXME: folder exists?
        $url = 'https://one.ubuntu.com/api/file_storage/v1';
        //FIXME: $path debe terminar en '/'
        $url .= str_replace(' ','%20',$path);
        //FIXME: $name no puede contener '/'
        $url .= str_replace(' ','%20',$name);

        $this->oauth->fetch($url,'{"kind":"directory"}',OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_PUT);
        print_r($this->oauth->getLastResponse());
    }
    function u1_file_exists($path){
        //FIXME: cache?
        $url = 'https://one.ubuntu.com/api/file_storage/v1';
        $url .= str_replace(' ','%20',$path);

        try{$this->oauth->fetch($url);}
        catch(OAuthException $E){if($E->lastResponse === '{"error": "not found"}'){return false;}}
        $i = $this->oauth->getLastResponseInfo();
        if($i['http_code'] === 200){}
        print_r($this->oauth->getLastResponseInfo());
    }
    function requestAuthentification($user,$pass,$name){
        $url = 'https://login.ubuntu.com/api/1.0/authentications?ws.op=authenticate&token_name=Ubuntu%20One%20@%20'.rawurlencode($name);
        $data = curlPetition(array('URL'=>$url,'USERPWD'=>$user.':'.$pass));
        //FIXME: check the response header -> 200
        $this->auth = json_decode($data['responseBody'],1);
    }
    function registerToken($user){
        $url = 'https://one.ubuntu.com/oauth/sso-finished-so-get-tokens/'.$user;
        $this->oauth->fetch($url);
        $r = $this->oauth->getLastResponse();
        if(substr($r,02) !== 'ok'){
            //FIXME: poner error
        }
        print_r($this->oauth->getLastResponse());
    }
    function saveAuth($fileName){$ar = fopen($fileName,'w');fwrite($ar,json_encode($this->auth));fclose($ar);return true;}
    function loadAuth($fileName){
        if(!file_exists($fileName)){return false;}
        $this->auth = json_decode(file_get_contents($fileName),1);
        if($this->auth === NULL){return false;}
        $this->oauth = new OAuth($this->auth['consumer_key'],$this->auth['consumer_secret'],OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1,OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI);
        $this->oauth->enableDebug();
        $this->oauth->enableSSLChecks();
        $this->oauth->setToken($this->auth['token'],$this->auth['token_secret']);
        return true;
    }
    function curlPetition($arr,$data = array()){
        $curl = curl_init($arr['URL']);
        if(!isset($data['URLTRACK'])){$data['URLTRACK'] = array();}
        $data['URLTRACK'][] = $arr['URL'];

        if(isset($this->curl['userAgent'])){curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$this->curl['userAgent']);}
        if(count($data['URLTRACK']) > 1){curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_REFERER,$data['URLTRACK'][count($data['URLTRACK'])-2]);}
        if(isset($arr['USERPWD'])){curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERPWD,$arr['USERPWD']);}
        if(isset($arr['userAgent'])){curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$arr['userAgent']);}
        if(isset($arr['POST'])){curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,true);curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$arr['POST']);}
        if(isset($arr['referer'])){curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_REFERER,$arr['referer']);}
        if(isset($arr['timeout'])){curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,$arr['timeout']);}
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,FALSE);
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,2);
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);

        if($this->curl['enableCookies'] !== false ){$cookieSrc = $this->curl['cookieSrc'];curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookieSrc);curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$cookieSrc);}
        if(isset($arr['header'])){curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$arr['header']);}
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,25);

        $viewcode = curl_exec($curl);
        $curlInfo = curl_getinfo($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        if(empty($viewcode)){return false;}
        $data['responseHeader'] = substr($viewcode,0,$curlInfo['header_size']);
        $data['responseBody'] = substr($viewcode,$curlInfo['header_size']);
        //$data['viewcode'] = $viewcode;

        if(isset($arr['FOLLOWLOCATION']) && preg_match('/HTTP\/1\.1 30[12]{1}/',$data['responseHeader'])){
            preg_match('/Location: (.*)/',$data['responseHeader'],$p);
            $nurl = trim($p[1]);
            if($nurl[0]=='/'){list($arr['URL'],) = explode('/',str_replace('http://','',$arr['URL']));$nurl = 'http://'.$arr['URL'].$nurl;}
            $arr['URL'] = $nurl;
            unset($arr['POST']);
            return curlPetition($arr,$data);
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
?>
```

Some example calls (srry for the disorder and commented code, maybe documentation one day):

```
echo time()."\n";
$ub = new ubuntuOne;
/* The first time you made the commented calls, then you save the authorization 
 * to a file. Once you have it on a file, you load it every time from there */
//$ub->requestAuthentification('sombra2eternity@gmail.com','*****','st');
//$ub->registerToken('sombra2eternity@gmail.com');
//print_r($ub->auth);
//$ub->saveAuth($GLOBALS['userPath'].'db/uOne.protected');
$ub->loadAuth($GLOBALS['userPath'].'db/uOne.protected');
//$ub->registerToken('sombra2eternity@gmail.com');
$ub->u1_getRoot();
//$ub->u1_file_exists('/~/Ubuntu One/non_exists/');
echo "\n";
$ub->u1_listFolder('/~/Ubuntu One/');
echo "\n";
$ub->u1_createFolder('new folder','/~/Ubuntu One/');
```

Good Luck, I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Updated version, some features added, some bug catched

```
    class ubuntuOne{
        var $curl = array('cookieSrc'=>'cookie.txt','enableCookies'=>false);
        var $auth = array('consumer_key'=>false,'consumer_secret'=>false,'token'=>false,'token_secret'=>false);
        var $oneInfo = false;
        var $oauth = false;
        var $E = array('errorCode'=>0,'errorDescription'=>'');
        var $fs = array();
        function ubuntuOne(){
            $this->fs['/'] = $this->helper_nodeSkeleton(array('name'=>'/','kind'=>'directory','resource_path'=>'/'));
        }
        function helper_nodeSkeleton($a = array()){return array_merge(array('name'=>false,'kind'=>false,'when_created'=>false,'generation'=>false,'has_children'=>false,'content_path'=>false,'generation_created'=>false,'parent_path'=>false,'resource_path'=>false,'when_changed'=>false,'key'=>false,'path'=>false,'volume_path'=>false,'size'=>0,'children'=>array()),$a);}
        function helper_storePath($path,$node = false){
            $path = explode('/',$path);
            $curPath = &$this->fs['/'];
            $resPath = '';
            foreach($path as $p){if($p === ''){continue;}$resPath .= '/'.$p;if(!isset($curPath['children'][$p])){$curPath['children'][$p] = $this->helper_nodeSkeleton(array('name'=>$p,'kind'=>'directory','resource_path'=>$resPath));}$curPath = &$curPath['children'][$p];}
            if($node !== false){$curPath = array_merge($curPath,$node);if($curPath['kind'] == 'file'){unset($curPath['children']);}}
        }
        function helper_storeNode($node){
            if(!isset($node['name'])){$r = preg_match('/\/([^\/]+)$/',$node['resource_path'],$name);if($r === 0){$this->E = array('errorCode'=>1,'errorDescription'=>'NAME_NOT_PARSED');return null;}$node['name'] = $name[1];}
            $this->helper_storePath($node['resource_path'],$node);
            $this->E = array('errorCode'=>0,'errorDescription'=>'');
        }
        function u1_getRoot(){
            if($this->oauth === false){return false;}
            $url = 'https://one.ubuntu.com/api/file_storage/v1';
            try{$this->oauth->fetch($url);}
            catch(OAuthException $E){print_r($E);return false;}
            $lr = json_decode($this->oauth->getLastResponse(),1);
            $this->helper_storePath($lr['root_node_path']);
            foreach($lr['user_node_paths'] as $np){$this->helper_storePath($np);}
            $this->oneInfo = $lr;
            return $lr;
        }
        function u1_getVolumeTree(){
            if($this->oneInfo === false){$r = $this->u1_getRoot();if($r === null){return $r;}}
            $base = $this->fs['/']['children']['~']['children'];
            foreach($base as $k=>$node){$this->u1_helper_getVolumeTree($node);}
            return $this->fs;
        }
        function u1_helper_getVolumeTree($node,$i = 0){
            if($node['kind'] == 'file'){return;}
            $r = $this->u1_folder_list($node['resource_path']);
            foreach($r['children'] as $child){$this->u1_helper_getVolumeTree($child,$i);}
        }
        function u1_folder_list($path){
            if($this->oauth === false){$this->E = array('errorCode'=>99,'errorDescription'=>'NO_OAUTH_DATA');return null;}
            if(substr($path,-1) != '/'){$path .= '/';}
            $url = 'https://one.ubuntu.com/api/file_storage/v1'.$this->helper_encodeURL($path).'?include_children=true';

            try{$this->oauth->fetch($url);}
            catch(OAuthException $E){echo $path;print_r($E);return null;}
            $lr = $this->oauth->getLastResponse();
            if($lr === '{"error": "not found"}'){return null;}
            $lr = json_decode($lr,1);

            /* Store the base node */
            $node = $lr;unset($node['children']);
            $this->helper_storeNode($node);
            foreach($lr['children'] as $child){$this->helper_storeNode($child);}
            return $lr;
        }
        function u1_folder_create($name,$path = '/~/Ubuntu One/'){
            if($this->oauth === false){$this->E = array('errorCode'=>99,'errorDescription'=>'NO_OAUTH_DATA');return null;}
            if(substr($path,-1) != '/'){$path .= '/';}
            $name = preg_replace(array('/[\.]$/','/[\/]*/'),'',$name);

            //FIXME: folder exists?
            $url = 'https://one.ubuntu.com/api/file_storage/v1'.$this->helper_encodeURL($path).$this->helper_encodeURL($name);

            $this->oauth->fetch($url,'{"kind":"directory"}',OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_PUT);
            $node = json_decode($this->oauth->getLastResponse(),1);
            $this->helper_storeNode($node);
            return $node;
        }
        function u1_file_create($path,$blob){
            if($this->oauth === false){$this->E = array('errorCode'=>99,'errorDescription'=>'NO_OAUTH_DATA');return null;}
            //if(substr($path,-1) != '/'){$path .= '/';}
            $url = 'https://files.one.ubuntu.com/content'.$this->helper_encodeURL($path);
            //FIXME: u1_file_exists

            $this->oauth->fetch($url,$blob,OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_PUT,array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));
            //$i = $this->oauth->getLastResponseInfo();
            //print_r($i);
            $node = json_decode($this->oauth->getLastResponse(),1);
            $this->helper_storeNode($node);
            return $node;
        }
        function u1_file_exists($path,$nocache = false){
            if($this->oauth === false){$this->E = array('errorCode'=>99,'errorDescription'=>'NO_OAUTH_DATA');return null;}
            //FIXME: cache?
            $url = 'https://one.ubuntu.com/api/file_storage/v1'.$this->helper_encodeURL($path);

            try{$this->oauth->fetch($url);}
            catch(OAuthException $E){if($E->lastResponse === '{"error": "not found"}'){return false;}}
            $i = $this->oauth->getLastResponseInfo();
            if($i['http_code'] === 200){}
            //FIXME: respuesta adecuada
            print_r($this->oauth->getLastResponseInfo());
        }
        function u1_file_get($contentPath,$destinyPath = false){
            if($this->oauth === false){$this->E = array('errorCode'=>99,'errorDescription'=>'NO_OAUTH_DATA');return null;}
            if(substr($contentPath,0,9) != '/content/'){$this->E = array('errorCode'=>1,'errorDescription'=>'NO_CONTENT_PATH');return null;}
            $url = 'https://files.one.ubuntu.com'.$this->helper_encodeURL($contentPath);

            /* I hope nobody ask me about the following concat, never gonna give you up!! */
            $time = time();
            $data = array('oauth_consumer_key'=>$this->auth['consumer_key'],'oauth_nonce'=>$time*rand(0,200),'oauth_signature_method'=>'HMAC-SHA1','oauth_timestamp'=>$time,'oauth_token'=>$this->auth['token'],'oauth_version'=>'1.0');
            $b = '';foreach($data as $k=>$v){$b .= '&'.$k.'='.$v;}
            $b = 'GET&'.rawurlencode($url).'&'.rawurlencode(substr($b,1));

            $key = $this->auth['consumer_secret'].'&'.$this->auth['token_secret'];
            $signature = $this->helper_oauth_hmacsha1($key,$b);

            $data['oauth_signature'] = $signature;
            $a = $url.'?';foreach($data as $k=>$v){$a .= $k.'='.rawurlencode($v).'&';}

            $h = fopen($a,'r');
            if(!$h){
                //FIXME: poner error
                return null;
            }

            //FIXME: is_writable
            //FIXME: file_exists
            $fileName = basename($contentPath);
            $ar = fopen($destinyPath.$fileName,'w');

            //FIXME: comprobar los primeros bits del buffer para asegurarse de que no está fallando
            $buffer = '';while(!feof($h)){$buffer = fgets($h,8192);fwrite($ar,$buffer);}fclose($h);

            fclose($ar);
            $filehash = sha1_file($destinyPath.$fileName);
            //echo "\n".$filehash."\n";

            return array('fileName'=>$fileName,'filePath'=>$destinyPath,'fileHash'=>$filehash);
        }
        function u1_file_unlink($path){
            if($this->oauth === false){$this->E = array('errorCode'=>99,'errorDescription'=>'NO_OAUTH_DATA');return null;}
            $url = 'https://one.ubuntu.com/api/file_storage/v1'.$this->helper_encodeURL($path);
            //FIXME: u1_file_exists

            try{$this->oauth->fetch($url,$blob,OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_DELETE,array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));}
            catch(OAuthException $E){print_r($E);$this->E = array('errorCode'=>1,'errorDescription'=>'FILE_NOT_EXISTS');return null;}
            $i = $this->oauth->getLastResponseInfo();
    //FIXME: eliminar el fichero de la caché
            //print_r($i);
        }
        function requestAuthentification($user,$pass,$name){
            $url = 'https://login.ubuntu.com/api/1.0/authentications?ws.op=authenticate&token_name=Ubuntu%20One%20@%20'.rawurlencode($name);
            $data = $this->curlPetition(array('URL'=>$url,'USERPWD'=>$user.':'.$pass));
            //FIXME: check the response header -> 200
            $this->auth = json_decode($data['responseBody'],1);
            if($this->auth === NULL){return false;}
            $this->oauth = new OAuth($this->auth['consumer_key'],$this->auth['consumer_secret'],OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1,OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI);
            $this->oauth->enableDebug();
            $this->oauth->enableSSLChecks();
            $this->oauth->setToken($this->auth['token'],$this->auth['token_secret']);
            return true;
        }
        function registerToken($user){
    //FIXME: check $this->oauth == false
            $url = 'https://one.ubuntu.com/oauth/sso-finished-so-get-tokens/'.$user;
            $this->oauth->fetch($url);
            $r = $this->oauth->getLastResponse();
            if(substr($r,02) !== 'ok'){
                //FIXME: poner error
            }
            //print_r($this->oauth->getLastResponse());
        }
        function saveAuth($fileName){$ar = fopen($fileName,'w');fwrite($ar,json_encode($this->auth));fclose($ar);return true;}
        function loadAuth($fileName){
            if(!file_exists($fileName)){return false;}
            $this->auth = json_decode(file_get_contents($fileName),1);
            if($this->auth === NULL){return false;}
            return $this->helper_makeOauth();
        }
        function setAuth($auth){$this->auth = $auth;return $this->helper_makeOauth();}
        function helper_makeOauth(){
            $this->oauth = new OAuth($this->auth['consumer_key'],$this->auth['consumer_secret'],OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1,OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI);
            $this->oauth->enableDebug();
            $this->oauth->enableSSLChecks();
            $this->oauth->setToken($this->auth['token'],$this->auth['token_secret']);
            return true;
        }
        function helper_encodeURL($url){return str_replace('%2F','/',rawurlencode($url));}
        function helper_oauth_hmacsha1($key,$data){
            $blocksize=64;$hashfunc='sha1';
            if(strlen($key)>$blocksize){$key=pack('H*',$hashfunc($key));}
            $key=str_pad($key,$blocksize,chr(0x00));
            $ipad=str_repeat(chr(0x36),$blocksize);
            $opad=str_repeat(chr(0x5c),$blocksize);
            $hmac=pack('H*',$hashfunc(($key^$opad).pack('H*',$hashfunc(($key^$ipad).$data))));
            return base64_encode($hmac);
        }
        function curlPetition($arr,$data = array()){
            //FIXME: data puede ser una propiedad de la clase
            $curl = curl_init($arr['URL']);
            if(!isset($data['URLTRACK'])){$data['URLTRACK'] = array();}
            $data['URLTRACK'][] = $arr['URL'];

            if(isset($this->curl['userAgent'])){curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$this->curl['userAgent']);}
            if(count($data['URLTRACK']) > 1){curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_REFERER,$data['URLTRACK'][count($data['URLTRACK'])-2]);}
            if(isset($arr['USERPWD'])){curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERPWD,$arr['USERPWD']);}
            if(isset($arr['userAgent'])){curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$arr['userAgent']);}
            if(isset($arr['POST'])){curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,true);curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$arr['POST']);}
            if(isset($arr['referer'])){curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_REFERER,$arr['referer']);}
            if(isset($arr['timeout'])){curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,$arr['timeout']);}
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,FALSE);
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,2);
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);

            if($this->curl['enableCookies'] !== false ){$cookieSrc = $this->curl['cookieSrc'];curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookieSrc);curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$cookieSrc);}
            if(isset($arr['header'])){curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$arr['header']);}
            curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,25);

            $viewcode = curl_exec($curl);
            $curlInfo = curl_getinfo($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            if(empty($viewcode)){return false;}
            $data['responseHeader'] = substr($viewcode,0,$curlInfo['header_size']);
            $data['responseBody'] = substr($viewcode,$curlInfo['header_size']);
            //$data['viewcode'] = $viewcode;

            if(isset($arr['FOLLOWLOCATION']) && preg_match('/HTTP\/1\.1 30[12]{1}/',$data['responseHeader'])){
                preg_match('/Location: (.*)/',$data['responseHeader'],$p);
                $nurl = trim($p[1]);
                if($nurl[0]=='/'){list($arr['URL'],) = explode('/',str_replace('http://','',$arr['URL']));$nurl = 'http://'.$arr['URL'].$nurl;}
                $arr['URL'] = $nurl;
                unset($arr['POST']);
                return $this->curlPetition($arr,$data);
            }

            return $data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: A quick example:

        $ub = new ubuntuOne;
        $r = $ub->requestAuthentification($arr['user'],$arr['pass'],$arr['name']);
        if($r === false){return json_encode(array('errorCode'=>2,'errorDescription'=>'AUTH_ERROR','file'=>__FILE__,'line'=>__LINE__));}
        $r = $ub->registerToken($arr['user']);
        if($r === false){return json_encode(array('errorCode'=>3,'errorDescription'=>'TOKEN_ERROR','file'=>__FILE__,'line'=>__LINE__));}
        $files = $ub->u1_getVolumeTree();
        print_r($files);

Answer (score 0):

Wow, Stuart Langridge, you are like a legend to me!!.

I think tomorrow I'll find a bit of spare time to hack in your example and see what I get. Meanwhile I worked out some Curl based functions to login and loot the UbuntuOne HTML page. I'll try to post it here as soon as I stabilize it a bit.

Yeah, I'll write an almost complete PHP based API and will notice you, only gimme some time, I'm kind of overload right now :S

I'll love to show you my work, maybe one day I will overcome my fears and apply to work in Canonical, it's like a dream for me. For the moment I have wrote a small review to show you my current project, I'll be happy to send you a copy if you care. I want to release it as Free Software but I'm one of those who needs to bunker a web project and be sure it's secure before release it.

(this is not any kind of perma-link, sorry)
http://marcos.colorvamp.com/mongo/lain-and-ubuntu-one/

And if you check the base page ... hmm like it's said on my land. "In the blacksmith's house, there are wooden knifes" :-)

Thanks for reply :-)

Comment: This stuff looks very cool! I'd be happy to have a chat about how you can tie into Ubuntu One most efficiently. I can then tell you about how to do what you want without screen-scraping the HTML pages, which we would like you not to do. :)

Comment: I'd feel very honored of get any hint from you. My project has some needs I work on (interface, core, security, js apps, permissions) so my progress is sometimes a bit slow, normally when I have to touch some areas. Im going to post here down a basic class that implements a very first steps of ubuntu One communication, is far from ready, but could point a few people in the right direction if they have any doubt. I will be updating it on the free time I could find and posting back here if its ok.

Comment: Anyway, when I finish my "Reveal" protocol I'd like to send you a copy and get your feedback if you have a little free time. Its full of "piglits" ( test cases, too much mesa-devel reading :) ) to avoid regressions that serve as examples. Maybe the UbuntuOne team could get some caching ideas from the code (I'm skeptical but still ...). Thanks for your time!

Comment: Definitely send me a copy and details and so on. I'm on irc as "aquarius" if you want to catch up for a chat, or we can skype or whatever :)